# Reporting within lightswitch web application

Tags: azure, silverlight-4.0, reporting, visual-studio-lightswitch

Currently I am working on a tool using Lightingswitch. It is a pretty straightforward tool and will be deployed as a webapplication on either Windows Azure or Amazon cloud service. 
Depending on the hosting it will either use Integrated Security, or Forms authentication. 
The client would like to generate a simple report based on the entered data. 
As we try to prevent using SSRS we would like to host this using a reportviewer within a ASPX page.

These are the things I came up with / tried, with the disadvantages / problems I ran into:

1. Hosting a seperate webapplication with the reports, and forward from the lightswitch tool to this webapplication. 
   Disadvantage of this would be the double hosting, and if the Forms Authentication is used, another login required for the reports.
2. Host the aspx page from within the SL application. I can simply manually upload the aspx pages to access the report, however, as these pages are not included in the package, they will be gone with an Azure Role Recycle.
3. Added the pages to the SL project, but they don't seem to be accessible after deployment.
4. Another option which I haven't tried yet, is creating a forms web application, and include the LS tool.
5. Still use SSRS / Azure Reporting, yet the problem remains using multiple logins.

Any suggestion on how to solve this issue / point me in the right direction is welcome.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could get it from your answer, the only annoying problem is the need to re-login after the report is generated via ASP.NET report viewer control.

Since both LightSwitch and ASP.NET applications are running on IIS, you might want to implement the custom logic for session sharing among several subdomains.

Imagine you have your reportingapp.com domain for your application, whereas LightSwitch frontend runs on `ls.reportingapp.com` and the reporting on `rp.reportingapp.com`. Then you first have to instruct IIS to set cookies to a common domain, in your case that would be `reportingapp.com`. You can reach it by using the following option in your `web.config` file:

```
<httpCookies domain=".reportingapp.com"/>
```

(*NB: the leading dot is important for cookies accessibility across subdomains!*)

This solutions will only partially works, because you have two IIS applications (LightSwitch counts as an IIS app too), not one, and the cookies will be sent twice. But you will be able to get the cookies for the domain using `HttpCookieCollection` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.aspx) in your ASP.NET application. Thereby you can implement a user session over several subdomains and avoid the repetitive logins.

Comment: Hi Alexander, 

Thank you for the quick response. The reportviewer will just be used to display the reports. Sadly enough your solution won't work in an azure environment. 

The domain for the app would be: lstool.azurewebsites.net, while the reporting would be: <randomstring.reporting.windows.net

Currently I am looking into hosting a .net application with a aspx page containing the LS tool, 
and/or finding a way to include the aspx pages containing the reportviewer in the deployment package so they survive the Azure role recycle.

Comment: @ISAF: The solution won't work for different domains, that's true (and you don't mention it under the requirements :) ), but you can always buy a DNS entry to point out to your Azure cloud services with unified domains.